# JQuery: click function still works after removeClass()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to enable event listener on a class, but it doesn't work

DOM element:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning shopping"> Shop </button>
```

Here is Javascript event listener:
Once function is done it removes .shopping so event doesn't triggers anymore.

```
$('.shopping').click(function(e){
    var that = this;
    alert( $(that).attr('class')); //btn btn-warning shopping

    //Ajax request
    $.get('processShopping.php', function(data){
    if(data == "success"){
        if($(that).hasClass('shopping')){
            $(that).removeClass('shopping');
            alert( $(that).attr('class'));//btn btn-warning
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Shopping class has been removed, but action still triggers!

Comment: The code you showed us has a typo, there is no string closer for the URL. Make sure this is not in your real code as well.

Comment: Yes, you're removing the class after succesful, so after that it should not work...

Comment: Indeed, I had a typo. It's stil working

Comment: If all else fails, try [.off](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that you need to use `event delegation`,

```
$('body').on('click', '.shopping', function(e){
```

In the above code, i have used `body` for an example purpose, but you have to use a static closest element on that.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Wait.. i'll come with an example

Comment: As much as I hate to agree with such a rude user, this solution actually works as event delegation *will* solve the problem.

Comment: This is insanely counterintuitive

Comment: @Brewal: Not really. The selector in a delegated event is run at *event time*, so the classes can come and go as they please and still match *when* they exist..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy +1 ...it ill added in my library

Comment: @Bala Ha ha.. We have been following a rule right?? aren't we? :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i know ...but i learned something  that is y i given +1

Answer (score 7):

### Cause

First, to explain why you still get a code-response to the event, you need to understand that `click()` attaches an event listener to the element *when that code runs*. It does not matter how the element changes afterwards as the listener is connected to the element selected by `$('.shopping')` and not the selector `$('.shopping')` itself.

### Solution

What you really needed was to created a delegated event handler. This will apply the selector at *event time*, **not** *when the code is run*.

You should connect a delegated event handler to a *non-changing ancestor* element. You should chose an ancestor that you know will always exist, but `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer to the desired elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.shopping', function(e){
```

This *will* work as the filter is applied *at event time*. When the class is removed the `click` function will not get called.

### Notes:

- Never use `body` for delegated events as it has a bug relating to styling (basically a 0 calculated body height will stop mouse events bubbling to `body`).
- Always use `document` as the default if nothing else is closer/convenient.
- `document` has the added bonus that document always exists, and the event happens later, so you do not need to put the event registration code into a document ready handler!